# Meaning of hdfs dfs -du -s -h

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I was given a command by my colleague to check the datasize of a table

```
hdfs dfs -du -s -h <table path>
```

I would like to check what does this command as i tried researching online , i could only find command on hdfs dfs du

also , after i query the above command , for e.g path table : hdfs://test/table_1

```
hdfs dfs -du -s -h  hdfs://test/table_1
```

it returns

```
29.3 K  141.7 hdfs://test/table_1
```

How can we determine the size of the table ? should we determine that the size of the table is 29.3 ?

Comment: In normal `du`, `-h` means human readable and `-s` means summarize

Answer (score 3):

As the [doc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/file_system_shell.html) says:

> The -s option will result in an aggregate summary of file lengths
> being displayed, rather than the individual files.

> The -h option will format file sizes in a "human-readable" fashion (e.g 64.0m instead of 67108864)

Also the output of `hdfs df -du` has two columns: [size]     [disk space consumed].
So the size of the table without replication is 29.3.